# Runtime Error unable to start Activity

Tags: java, android

I get this run-time error after I try to run my app, which is a simple calculator with 5 buttons and 2 EditText and 1 TextView.

MainActivity.java:

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
   Button sum,sub,mult,div,clear;
   TextView tv;
   EditText e,e1;
   float num1,num2,result;
   String oper;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sum=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_sum);
    sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_sub);
    mult=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_mul);
    clear=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_clear);
    sum=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_sum);
    e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    sum.setOnClickListener(this);
    sub.setOnClickListener(this);
    mult.setOnClickListener(this);
    div.setOnClickListener(this);
    clear.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    num1 = Float.parseFloat(e.getText().toString());
    num2 = Float.parseFloat(e1.getText().toString());
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(e.getText().toString())&&TextUtils.isEmpty(e1.getText().toString()))
    {
        tv.setText("Error");
        return;
    }
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button_sum:
           oper="+";
            result=num1+num2;
            break;
        case R.id.button_sub:
             oper="-";
            result=num1-num2;
            break;
        case R.id.button_mul:
             oper="*";
            result=num1*num2;
            break;
        case R.id.button_div:
            oper="/";
            result=num1/num2;
            break;
       case R.id.button_clear:
           tv.setText("");
           e.setText("");
          e1.setText("");
           break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    tv.setText(num1 + " " + oper + " " + num2 + " = " + result);
}
}
```

---

xml layout :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="+"
    android:id="@+id/button_sum"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-"
    android:id="@+id/button_sub"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_sum"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_sum"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_sum" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="*"
    android:id="@+id/button_mul"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_sub"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_sub" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="/"
    android:id="@+id/button_div"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_mul"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_mul" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_sub"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_sub"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_sub"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="clear"
    android:id="@+id/button_clear"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_sub"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_sum"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_sum" />
```

logcat:

```
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.megam.myapplication, PID: 1798
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.megam.myapplication/com.example.megam.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.megam.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
11-29 05:04:47.493 1798-1798/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
11-29 05:04:47.501 1798-1800/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 212K, 8% free 3199K/3464K, paused 5ms+1ms, total 11ms
11-29 05:04:49.337 1798-1798/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1798 SIG: 9
```

It used to work before I added the clear button.

Comment: can you post the onCreate?

Comment: post your xml code also,

Comment: Please post the code line no. 32

Comment: First make sure that all the ids of the view correctly map to their corresponding Java objects. If not maybe that is resulting in the NPE(Null Pointer Exception).If it worked before you added the button to clear the view then probably the code to blame is in the `case R.id.button:...`. The `oper` that is used in the last statement where you set the textview is not initialized and thus leading to a null over there because the clear button does not initialize/make changes to the `oper`.

Comment: please add your onCreate method

Comment: Your clear button  may not be found by the id you gave in your xml. make sure the id of clear button in xml and in your activity, `findViewById(R.id.clear_button_id)` are same. Please post your full code for MainActivity.java so that others can understand

Comment: i edited the question with compelet MainActivity.java and xml layout file, thanks anyway

Comment: @MohamedRa where is line 32 in your code?!!

Comment: @NarayanAcharya its working now , many thanks